# Get number of Virtual Machines in QEMU?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal, qemu

How to get number of Vitual Machines in QEMU ??

Suppose, I have 1 VM then I wanna to get only 1 not something else...

No any type of Heading or other. Remove these type of heading like in picture:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Run this command:

```
ps -eo comm | grep -c ^qemu-
```

Answer (score 0):

QEMU always runs exactly one VM at once. If you have multiple VMs running, then you have multiple QEMU processes running.

You may be using a "virtual machine management layer" program such as libvirt; if so, it probably provides a mechanism for listing virtual machines (including ones that are not currently running). How to do that will depend on what VM management software you're using.